# Oracle Data Guard - Wrong Path with new created Data Files

Tags: oracle, datafile, dataguard, standby

I've created a Standby Database with the following duplicate command:

```
run {
duplicate target database for standby from active database
spfile
parameter_value_convert 'ORCL','ORCLSTBY'
set db_name='ORCL'
set db_unique_name='ORCLSTBY'
set db_create_file_dest='/u01/app/oracle/oradata/ORCLSTBY'
set db_recovery_file_dest='/u01/app/oracle/oradata/ORCLSTBY'
set db_file_name_convert='/ORCL/','/ORCLSTBY/'
set log_file_name_convert='/ORCL/','/ORCLSTBY/'
set standby_file_management='AUTO'
;
}
```

During the duplicate command the existing datafile location are correctly overwritten from '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/ORCL' to '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/ORCLSTBY' on Stanby Instance.
After I've activated the Data Guard Broker:

```
DGMGRL> CREATE CONFIGURATION adgconfig AS PRIMARY DATABASE IS ORCL CONNECT IDENTIFIER IS ORCL;
DGMGRL> ADD DATABASE ORCLSTBY AS CONNECT IDENTIFIER IS ORCLSTBY MAINTAINED AS PHYSICAL;
DGMGRL> ENABLE CONFIGURATION;
```

When I try to create a new datafile on primary instance here comes the problems:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE TBS_TEST ADD DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/ORCL/TEST02.dbf' size 100m;
```

On the Standby side the new file is create under the wrong directory with worng name (example: /u01/app/oracle/oradata/ORCLSTBY/datafile/qwt9yr_test2.dbf)

Anyone know what's wrong on my configuration?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `db_create_file_dest`, you enabled [Oracle Managed Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/using-oracle-managed-files.html) in the standby database, so the database generated a path using the value of this parameter, the value of `db_unique_name` and the name of tablespace.

If you don't want to use OMF, unset `db_create_file_dest`.